# Am i using the proper getter/setter methods?

Tags: java

I'm currently learning how to code and on my first module final. Before I can move on I must complete the assignment. When I input my code it returns with 1 error. The code is listed below. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

```
public class Driver extends User { 
    
    private Driveable vehicle = new Vehicle();
    
    public Driver() {}//mine
    public Driver(Vehicle vehicle, String name, String email){
        this();
        setVehicle(vehicle);
        setName(name);
        setEmail(email);
       }
 
 
  
     public Driveable getVehicle(){
      return vehicle;
     }
     public Drivable setVehicle(){
        this.vehicle;
     }
 
    
     public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
         this.vehicle = vehicle;
     }
    
     public void drive(){
        vehicle.drive();
     }
}
```

Error methods are listed below as well,

```
            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1 error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
class Driver does contain the required methods.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Check class Vehicle  getter/setter methods.                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TaxiService                                                                                                                                                                                
        at Test.taxiService(Test.java:56)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        at Test.main(Test.java:16)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TaxiService                                                                                                                                                                                              
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)                                                                                                                                                                                 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)                                                                                                                                                                                      
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)                                                                                                                                                                              
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)                                                                                                                                                                                      
        ... 2 more
```

Comment: public void setVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
         this.vehicle = vehicle;
     }
why is Vehicle vehicle? (String vechicle) the vehicle is of string type and by reading the question i can guide better.

Comment: If you would like, i can walk you through this over a voice call?
My discord is Jakob#8641 if interested :)

Comment: The class `Driver` is missing one or more methods that are expected by the test framework - check your requirements to determine what is missing. The second error indicates a class is missing (`TaxiService`).  It seems to be referenced by your `Vehicle` class which is not included in the question.  It is unclear to me if you are supposed to define `TaxiService` - check your requirements.

Comment: How far we've fallen that a *first course* in programming is treating the use of getters/setters as fundamental to programming. It's a hack used to get uniform access in a language that doesn't have it (read: Java), not some fundamental principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new, so pls forgive any error I make.

emm.. first things first on the third line of code
`private Driveable vehicle = new Vehicle();`

you should not be giving assignments here, and the Class types also doesn't match
`private Driveable vehicle;` is enough.

if you still want to initialize the attribute, do it in the constructor method.

your getter looks fine, but in the first setter, I'm not sure what you want to do by taking no input but to return an object reference.

Note that the vehicle is of type Driveable and it seems you want to use it as Vehicle type in your code after definition, so consider fixing that.

Comment: Thank you that worked! It's my first week so im still trying to learn it all. I appreciate the help!